# How do I make a user input array or list in python?

Tags: arcmap, python-2.6

I don't know which one I need actually because I am relatively new to python. What my goal is to have a stand alone script to run multiple buffers based on user input. For example, I would like to ask the user how many buffers and then ask them what those buffers are.

How many buffers do you have? 3
What distances would you like to buffer? 50, 150, 250

I want to get all the input information before running the buffer tool. I'm guessing I need some type of loop.

Answer (score 6):

There is a built-in script tool that does exactly this: [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001p000000)

[image: Screenshot of the Multiple Ring Buffer tool dialog]

You can right-click it and go to edit to see the source Python script for its implementation.

If you want to roll your own (as a script tool), the key to the implementation is a multi-value parameter (of type *double*) for the distances, which at runtime is passed as a semicolon-delimited string argument, which you can then split up into a Python list object using [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), which you can then loop over using a `for` statement and create the buffers iteratively.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module (which you can download separately if you're not using Python 2.7). Specifically the [`nargs`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#nargs) keyword, which automatically puts your data into a list. For example:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Make some buffers')
parser.add_argument('buffers', metavar='distance', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='Buffer distances')

args = parser.parse_args()
print "Number of buffers: %i" % len(args.buffers)
```

Comment: Note you can do similar with the [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module, which is native to 2.6, but it's more complex.